# Form design window not visible in Windows form application of Visual Studio

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio

I accidentally closed my form designer window (the place where we put buttons and all). Now, when I reopened the project, it's not coming up. Nothing is present in solution explorer also. I explored the complete project folder, but couldn't find anything.

Designer view:
[image: Snapshot]

Solution Explorer view:
[image: solution explorer pic]

Comment: You've obviously still got the designer code file so you appear to be wrong when you said that you couldn't find anything in the Solution Explorer or the project folder. I guess the question is whether you still have the user code file. I also have to wonder whether the fact that the file and the class have different names is an indication that you mucked something up by changing the type name in one code file but not the other. In future change the file name in the Solution Explorer and that will prompt to change the type name automatically. Is there a Form2.vb file? What class name is in it?

Comment: Yes, Form2.vb file is there in the folder. By "couldn't find anything in the Solution Explorer" I meant, I couldn't find anything that can help me bring back the designer window. Can you just guide me, if designer window is closed once, how to bring it back? Sorry, if I caused confusion earlier.

Comment: Were you planning on answering my second question?

Comment: Clearly you've been editing the Designer.vb file by hand.  Very bad idea, changes in this file must only be made by the designer.  Manual changes can easily push it into a state where the designer no longer understands what it contains.  No more designer view.  Restore from source control to recover.

Answer (score 0):

In "solution explorer", find your `Form2.Designer.vb`. Then, *right click* -> *View Designer* (or something like that: I don't use the english version of Visual Studio). See the following screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]

I have Visual Studio in Italian, but the icons are the same and it's quite intuitive...

PS: If this doesn't work, there is probably an error in the code, which we cannot analyze without seeing it.

Comment: I have updated solution explorer snapshot in the question. I do not see icons like yours.

Comment: Try to right click on Form2.vb (parent of Form2.Designer.vb) and click on _View Designer_

Comment: I have updated snapshot after right clicking. I do not see the option as highlighted in your snapshot.

Comment: Mmmm... Probably there is some mistakes in the code behind. Try to undo your last modification in the code (ex, if you've added an inner class, try to remove it). As another option, create a new project and try to copy the code a little at a time to understand what causes this "error".

Comment: To understand if the design view works (and I think so), just right click on the project name in solution explorer and add a new Windows form. The view will automatically open.

Answer (score 0):

- Both of the form files (`Form2.vb` and `Form2.Designer.vb`) must contain a `Partial Class` definition with the same class name.
- These files must not contain other top-level types (classes, structs, etc.) definitions. Nested types are okay.
- Ideally the file names match the class name. This also includes `Form2.resx` if avail.

Assuming that you did want to rename your form to `Todolist`, you should now have:

```vb
' File: Todolist.vb
Public Class Todolist
   '...
End Class
```

```vb
' File: Todolist.Designer.vb
<Global.Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.DesignerGenerated()> _
Partial Class Todolist
    Inherits System.Windows.Forms.Form
   '...
End Class
```

And don't forget to rename any `.resx` file: `Todolist.resx`

---

Next time, if you want to rename a form: Do it in the Solution explorer and rename `Form2.vb` to `Todolist.vb`. A dialog will pop up:

> You are renaming a file. Would you also like to perform a rename in this project of all references to the code element `Form2`?

Click <kbd>Yes</kbd>

All the 3 files and the 2 partial classes will be renamed accordingly, plus any code that uses `Form2` will now automatically use `Todolist`.